# Get the client's IP address in socket.io version > 1.3

Tags: javascript, node.js, socket.io

When using socket.IO (Version > 1.3) in a `Node.js` Server, is there an easy way to get the IP address of an incoming connection? It always show me server IP address. I need to get the Client IP Address.

I tried using

console.log(socket.handshake.headers['x-forwarded-for'] || `socket.request.connection.remoteAddress);`

But it shows 127.0.0.0. I am using `socket.io` Version 1.3.7. Please Help me out.

Comment: use this `socket.request.connection.remoteAddress`

Comment: @ÖzgürErsil : I tried the same but it is showing 127.0.0.1 which is server IP but i  need client IP address.

Comment: Are you trying to connect from `localhost` ?

Comment: @Cyrbil: Yes But i also tried the same on live server and its giving me server IP not the client one.

Comment: How did you try it on live server?

Comment: Pretty sure you tried on the same host (`local` or your `server`). You need to try from your `local computer`, connecting to `the server`.  Also, don't use `socket.handshake.headers['x-forwarded-for']` as this is only useful when you have a proxy between you and your app.

Comment: @HopefulLlama : By  io.on('connection', function(socket) {console.log(socket.request.connection.remoteAddress)});

Comment: I mean, is the live server, physically a different machine than the machine you used to connect to it?

Comment: @HopefulLlama: Yes live server is a different machine.

Comment: Do you have something between your app and your client (proxy, webserver, loadbalancer ... ) ?

Comment: @Cyrbil : Yes on live server we are using Hproxy.

Comment: Does your haproxy configuration includes a [forwardfor](https://cbonte.github.io/haproxy-dconv/configuration-1.5.html#4-option%20forwardfor) statement ?

Comment: Oups, not an haproxy, I don't know for hproxy, but you will need it to somehow send the connecting ip in an `x-forwarded-for` header.

Answer (score 0):

you can use `socket.client.conn.remoteAddress`

Comment: it may be because your client is running on localhost too

Comment: I have just checked it in my local network and it works like a charm